# Can somebody explain why this is happening

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, operands

We have: `(set1,set2)`

why does `print(set1 or set2)` return `set1` instead of `(set1 | set2)`
and `print(set1 and set2)` return `set2` instead of `set1.intersection(set2)` ?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I think the duplicate is not quite right. OP asks why there is a difference between `and` and `&`, and `or` and `|`. They don't ask why `or` and `and` return a non boolean value

Comment: `and` is the boolean operand, equivalent to `&&` in other languages you might be familiar with. `&` is the bitwise `and` in Python, which in sets is wired to call the `set.intersection` method (actually, it is the other way around but the idea stands). Same goes for `or`, `|` and `union`.

Comment: @DeepSpace Right, there are two parts to the question, I added a second duplicate about `&` and `and`.

Answer (score 0):

That is how boolean operand works

- `or`

  - if left operand is `True/Truthy` => return it
  - if left operand is `False/Falthy` => return right operand
- `and`

  - if left operand is `False/Falthy` => return it
  - if left operand is `True/Truthy` => return right operand

Comment: This is not quite what OP asks. They ask why `set1 and set2` does not call `set1.intersection`